# Spring security 3.2.0 > <security:form-login /> deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a problem with spring security 3.2.0 RC1

I'm using the tags to connect me

```
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/paginas/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/publico/login.xhtml" always-use-default-target="true" 
    default-target-url="/paginas/funcionario.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/publico/login.xhtml?login_error=1"/>

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/publico/login.xhtml"/>
    <security:remember-me/>
</security:http>


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSourceMySQL"
        users-by-username-query="select usuario, senha, ativo from funcionario where usuario = ?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select f.usuario, f.permissao from funcionario f where f.usuario = ?"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

`<security:form-login />`

This says "Method 'setFilterProcessesUrl' is marked deprecated"

`<security:logout />`

This says "Method 'setFilterProcessesUrl' is marked deprecated"

Could someone tell me any alternative?
Thanks!

Comment: This link may help you :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569030/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-httpelement-and-deprecated-method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer can help you.

However, the warning message generated by IDE is not a big problem because you did not use the deprecated method.

I'm using spring security too and I also can see the same warning message but the service is working perfectly.

I'm sorry if the answer is not you wanted.